# perl based cron job won't write to mounted cifs/windows share ONLY after long inactivity

Tags: perl, ubuntu, cron, samba, cifs

I'm not sure how to title that more succinctly and still have it be meaningful.

(Note that this works fine when run mid-day, via cron or manually, so I "know" the script itself is sound.)

I have a cron job (ubuntu 13.04.)
It runs as my user (not root.)

The job itself runs at 6:00 in the morning. It's the first 'business level' job that runs all day.

```
1 6 * * 1-5 /home/me/bin/run_perl_job
```

run_perl_job is just:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/me/bin
./script.pl
```

The script copies a file to "/mnt/shared_drive/outputfile.xls"

The mount point is defined in fstab as:

```
//fileserver/share /mnt/shared_drive cifs user=domain/me%password,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Now. Given that:

- When I run the script in a normal shell, it works fine.
- When I look at the mount point first thing in the morning (via a normal terminal) it shows up (and is writeable) without event.
- When I copy the crontab line and set it to run in a couple minutes, to see the symptom, it works fine (creates the file quite happily.)

The ONLY time this fails is if it's running in its normal time slot (6:01).  The rest of the script functions ( the file itself has to be pulled down via sftp, etc.) So I know it's not dying.

It's driving me batty because the test cycle is 24 hours.

I just added the following couple lines to the beginning of the 'run_perl_job' script, hoping it exposes something tomorrow:

```
cd /mnt/shared_drive
ls -lrt >>home/me/bin/process.log
```

But I'm stumped.  "It's almost as though" the mount point had gotten stale overnight and is waiting for some kind of access attempt before remounting.  I'd run "mount -a" at the top of the 'run_perl_job' script if I could reasonably do it. But given that it's got to be sudo'ed, that doesn't seem reasonable to me.

Thoughts?  I'm running out of ideas and this test cycle is awful.

Answer (score 0):

how about putting a

```
   umount -f -v /mnt/shared_drive
   mount -v -a
```

into a root cron job just before your script runs. That way you don't need to sudo in your script and have the password in plain sight. -v might give you a hint on what is happening to make it stale

Comment: At this point I'll try most anything.  I did ALmost that (just a 'mount -a') to no avail.  In fact even the ls redirected in to the file worked, which stumps me entirely.